# I have 2 ArrayList and I need a way to use 2 iterators

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, bluej

So I been working on BlueJ and right now I have found a small problem don't know if the solution is easy but I'm stuck at a part that I need to maybe use 2 iterators but can´t seem to make them work.

the problem that I have is with the last part of the code

```
for (Iterator i = cliente.iterator(); i.hasNext(); & Iterator j = articulo.iterator(); j.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(i.next());
    System.out.println(j.next());
```

It works fine with only 1 ArrayList and 1 iterator, when I only use the `iterator i`, it gives me all the info that is on that array same if I only use the `iterator j` that is without putting articulo when I use the i or without cliente when I use j. So yea thing I need to work is that it gives me all the info that is in boths arrays, don't know if there is a way to do it differently but that's why I ask.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Encabezado
{
private ArrayList<Cliente> cliente;
private ArrayList<Articulo> articulo;
private String NFactura;
private String fecha;

public Encabezado()
{
    cliente = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
    articulo = new ArrayList<Articulo>();
}

public Encabezado(String NFactura, String fecha)
{
    cliente = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
    articulo = new ArrayList<Articulo>();
    this.NFactura = NFactura;
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public void AgregarCliente(Cliente c)
{
    cliente.add(c);
}

public void AgregarArticulo(Articulo a)
{
    articulo.add(a);
}

public void verFactura () 
{
    System.out.println("Factura: " + NFactura);
    for (Iterator i = cliente.iterator(); i.hasNext(); & Iterator j = articulo.iterator(); j.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(i.next());
        System.out.println(j.next());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to use two iterator simultaneously you can do as below,

```
Iterator<Cliente> i = cliente.iterator();
Iterator<Articulo> j = articulo.iterator();

while (i.hasNext() && j.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(i.next());
    System.out.println(j.next());
}
```

Comment: So there is no problem omitting and changing all the ArrayList for just Iterator?